# How to add external assets file in rails 4 project?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an external `css`, `javascript` and `Images` files in a separate project and wanted to include in my new `rails` project. Here is my structure of folders:

```
external-assets/js/ <Files>
external-assets/js/plugin/<Files>
external-assets/css/<Files>
external-assets/css/plugins/<Files>
external-assets/images/<some Folders>/<Files>
external-assets/images/<Files>
```

So, I copied `external-assets/js` folder to `app/assets/javascript` and for `css` I copied `external-assets/css` to `app/assets/stylesheets`.

and replace `<link rel="icon" href="external-assets/css/plugins/bootstrap.min.css">` to `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/plugins/bootstrap.min.css" %>` in my `html.erb` file. I followed the same thing for other `css` files and `js` files. When I start the server I got this error:

```
Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( style.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

After searching on `SO post` like: [Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `config.assets.precompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970573/asset-filtered-out-and-will-not-be-served-add-config-assets-precompile) and 
[Asset filtered out and will not be served](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673036/asset-filtered-out-and-will-not-be-served). I need to mention my all `js` and `css` files to `config.assets.precompile`.

## Questions

1) Do I really need to mention all of `js`, `css` and `images` file? I know the reason but I do have a lot of assets files.

2) What about If I put them in `public` folder? Is it good approach?

3) There is `stylesheet_link_tag` for css , `javascript_link_tag` for js. What about Images?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I really need to mention all of js, css and images file? I know the reason but I do have a lot of assets files.

No.

Sprockets has the `require` directives which concatenate any files you ["require"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark) into your `application` file...

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require x
```

What you want? Probably not... but it at least gives you the ability to call one file (`application`), whilst benefitting from the content of all the others.

> 2) What about If I put them in public folder? Is it good approach?

No.

Precompiling assets puts the [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) versions into `public/assets` anyway.

> 3) There is stylesheet_link_tag for css , javascript_link_tag for js. What about Images?

[`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag)

---

**Assets**

I think you're getting confused about the role of "external" assets.

If an asset is *truly* external (such as [Google's JQuery repo](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)), you'll be able to reference them by using the `javascript_include_tag` or `stylesheet_link_tag` respectively:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" %>
```

This will basically add the following to your layout at runtime:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If this is what you want, you'll be best adding the external repos calls to your `#app/views/layouts/application` file (as above).

-

**Rails Assets**

*However*....

They're obviously **not** "external" assets if you have them stored locally.

So you're either going to have to call them from their real external repositories, or use them *locally* in your app.

If you're happy using them locally (which carries the responsibility of keeping them updated), you may wish to look at [Rails Assets](http://rails-assets.org):

[image]

This is a gem repository (you have to add `source https://rails-assets.org` to your `Gemfil`), which allows bundler to ping their server for asset-based gems.

It is meant to work like [Bower](http://bower.io/) - taking any of the public repos and converting them into gems. It allows you to call external repos into your app:

```
#Gemfile
gem "rails-assets-jquery.easing"

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery.easing
```

This will basically store a *local* version of the JS / CSS you wish to use in your asset pipeline, allowing you to include it with the sprockets `require` directive.

The big difference is that since these assets are downloaded through the *gem* system, they will be updated each time you run `bundler`.

We use it, and although it can be a little tricky sometimes, it's well worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation (I was expecting your answer :) ) But How about those custom css and js I added in my external project? How can I add them in rails project? When I am adding them getting error post in post

Answer (score 1):

1. Either put it all into the public directory, and then use the html `<script>`, `<link>`, `≤img>` tags to reference the assets. You will lose some Sprockets features like minification and digesting, but that's not a big deal.
2. Mention all the assets in the `application.css` / `application.js`, or create a new manifest file, e.g. `custom.css` / `custom.js`, list the assets to use here and then add those two files into the:

   ```
   Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( custom.css custom.js )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have require _ tree in your application.js & application.css? 
If not, just add it to both files and restart your server.

> The require_tree directive tells Sprockets to recursively include all JavaScript files in the specified directory into the output. These paths must be specified relative to the manifest file. You can also use the require_directory directive which includes all JavaScript files only in the directory specified, without recursion.

[Check out this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Hope it helps. :)